Python script gets stuck due to mysql query running for longer period
Mysql version - 5.7
Python version - 3.9.2
I have a dynamic mysql query, which sometimes runs for over 10 mins or something and the mysql's set timeout has been set to around 1 minute. Which is why i believe when the mysql query is ready with the output (around 10 mins after the query was fired), it goes to null state (refer to the image below, the last line where the state of the query is sleep and info is null)

Due to this, my python script gets stuck half way and does not execute any further unless i kill the query manually. Note that i am a beginner here in python and here's the structure of my script-
I've made a function which executes the query, which establishes a connection and executes the given query and returns the output. Everything else is written in the main function itself, no threading used.
I have checked sqlalchemy but didnt understand it properly how to implement it here.
Can someone please tell me how do i get rid of this issue? Also, if there is any optimized way to write the script?
What i did was -
I executed a python script which establishes mysql connections and executes multiple queries, out of which one query is dynamically created which may sometimes take some while to execute. Since it takes very long time to execute, the connection gets broken and my script gets stuck midway, nothing gets executed even after i kill the query manually, i get an error - mysql connection not available.
EDIT -
Here's the sample code:
def execute_qry(qry,conn_details):
    cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
    try:
        # Process results
        cursor.execute(query)
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return result_set
    except (mysql.connector.Error) as err:
        print(f"Error: {err}")
        report_fail = f'''
                        UPDATE status_table
                        SET status_flag = 3
                        WHERE id = 1'''
        execute_qry(report_fail,master_db_conn)
        sys.exit()
    except (mysql.OperationalError) as err:
        print(f" Error: {err}")
        # Handle reconnection if connection lost
        # if err.errno == mysql.connector.errorcode.CR_SERVER_LOST:
        conn.reconnect(attempts=3, delay=2)  # Reconnect with retries and delay
        return execute_qry(query,conn)  # Retry the query 



try:

    *establish mysql connection here*

    main_qry = ''' CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS 
                   SELECT col1, col2, ...
                   FROM old_tbl'''

    result = execute_qry(main_qry,mysql_connection_details)

except:

    print('Query Execution Failed')
    update_qry = 'UPDATE status_tbl set status_flag = 3 WHERE id = 1'
    result = execute_qry(update_qry,mysql_connection_details)



your code should be able to recover from a closed connection. Do you have your code inside try/except clauses that try to reconnect to the database if the connection is lost? You should make a minimal reproducible example of code that executes such query, then post it.

@Elerium115 i have edited and added as much code as possible, thanks!
